# Passing virtual function pointer as argument of a Base Class function

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions

First I have created a custom type as follows:

`typedef void* (*FUNCPTR)(void*);`

Then, I created a  Base Class called `P`.

```
class P
{
  ...

  public:
    virtual void job() = 0; // Pure virtual function

    void start()
    {
      create((FUNCPTR) &P::job);
    }
  ...
};
```

(`create` method signature accepts `void *(*__start_routine)(void *)`.)

Next, I create a Derived Class called `PD` where I have implemented the pure virtual function `job()`.

When trying to compile the following error is raised:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNwL4X6.o: in function P::start()': undefined reference to P::job()
```

- Am I not implementing the virtual function correctly?
- Perhaps, at link-time `P::job()` is not being called, instead `PD::job()`, and it is causing the error?

**Edit 1. Minimal reproducible example.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

typedef void* (*THREADPTR)(void*);

class P
{
    protected:
        pthread_t thread;

    public:
        virtual void job() = 0;

        void start()
        {
            cout << "P::start()" << endl;
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (THREADPTR) &P::job, (void*) this);
        }
};

class PD: public P
{
    public:
        void job()
        {
            cout << "PD::job()" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    P *pd;

    pd = new PD();
    pd->start();
}
```

**Edit 2. Provide desired functionality.**

I would love to code only the logic for the `job()` function for in each class that extends the abstract one.

**Edit 3. Detailed information about the `create()` function.**

The `create()` function was oversimplified because not so much attention to it was expected. But was not the case, it is a fundamental part of the problem. With that being said, the actual function is this:

```
extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
               const pthread_attr_t *__restrict __attr,
               void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
               void *__restrict __arg) __THROWNL __nonnull ((1, 3));
```

as defined in `pthread.h`

The minimal reproducible example was modified to account for this.

**Edit 4. Question marked as duplicate.**

The question marked as duplicate does not match with the intentions that were laid out here. The solution was tried without success giving the parser already the error: `virtual void P::job() argument of type "void (P::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(*)(void *)"C/C++(167)`

Comment: You cannot use a class function pointer to pass to that function. It needs to be a free or static function.

Comment: "create firm method accepts void *(*__start_routine)(void *)" thats not going to work. `P::job` is a member function. It needs an object to be called. It cannot convert to a pointer to free function. Anyhow, please post a [mcve]

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You cannot take an address of pure virtual function because its definition does not exist (of course). You certainly cannot cast it to an ordinary function pointer.

Comment: Hint: The `void*` parameter of that function can be probably used, to have a `this` pointer of `P` passed to it during the callback.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example was posted as requested.

Comment: @rober_dinero and I already told you, what's the main problem with your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It gives the following error: `/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc20YzOb.o: in function `P::start()':
minimalExample.cpp:(.text._ZN1P5startEv[_ZN1P5startEv]+0x13): undefined reference to `P::job()'`. 

My goal is to only code the specific `job()` function logic in each derivation of the abstract class. I could make the `start()` virtual but it would create a lot of duplicated code. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You **cannot** achieve your goal as long as you have `(THREADPTR) &P::job` in there. It is invalid. It is not going to work. Don't do this.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. How it should be done then?

Comment: It depends on how strongly you are attached to the signature of `create`. You call it "firm method", I'm not familiar with the term. Is this something given to you by a third party? Can you change the signature?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It cannot be changed. By "firm method" I was trying to refer to the signature of the method. I got confused with my mother language. I am sorry for the inconvenience it may have caused.

Comment: Is there a `void *` parameter to `create`? What are the requirements for the return value of a `THREADPTR` function?

Comment: `create` is actually `pthread_create`. Please refer to the 3rd edit. The `THREADPTR` will not return anything. Just execute some job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that it's been clarified that `create` is infact `pthread_create`, you can have

```
class P
{   
        static void* do_job(void* self) 
        {
            static_cast<P*>(self)->job(); 
            return nullptr; 
        }
        pthread_t thread;
    public:
        virtual void job() = 0;

        void start()
        {
            pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &P::do_job, this);
            cout << "P::start()" << endl;

        }
};
```

Comment: A bold assumption, that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. hooray for bold assumptions :p

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a non-static member function, you need to bind it with the existing object, because non-static member function has implicit `this` parameter. One possible solution is to create an intermediate object to keep the pointer to non-static member function and to the object using `std::bind`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using THREADFUNC = void();

void create(std::function<THREADFUNC> f){
    std::cout << "create()" << std::endl;
    std::invoke(f);
}

class P {
public:
    virtual void job() = 0;

    void start() {
        std::cout << "P::start()" << std::endl;
        create(std::bind(&P::job, this));
    }
};

class PD : public P {
public:
    void job() {
        std::cout << "PD::job()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    P* pd = new PD();
    pd->start();
}
```

**Edit:**

> The `create()` method signature can not be changed.

If it is not possible to change the signature of `void create(void*(*__start_routine)(void*))` function, it is possible to use CRTP idiom (see answer from @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.) or it is also possible to keep the necessary context inside `P` class implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>

void create(void* (*__start_routine)(void*)){
    std::cout << "create()" << std::endl;
    std::invoke(__start_routine, nullptr);
}

class P {
public:
    virtual void job() = 0;

    void start() {
        std::cout << "P::start()" << std::endl;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_worker_list_mutex);
            m_workers.push_back(this);
        }
        create(&P::job_starter);
    }

private:
    static void* job_starter(void*) {
        P* worker_ptr = nullptr;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_worker_list_mutex);
            worker_ptr = m_workers.front();
            m_workers.pop_front();
        }
        worker_ptr->job();
        return nullptr;
    }

    static std::list<P*> m_workers;
    static std::mutex m_worker_list_mutex;
};

std::list<P*> P::m_workers;
std::mutex P::m_worker_list_mutex;

class PD : public P {
public:
    void job() {
        std::cout << "PD::job()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    P* pd = new PD();
    pd->start();
}
```

Comment: The `create()` method signature can not be changed.